# how to sync local git repo with changes made on website

Tags: git, github

I've made some changes to a repo on GitHub through the edit functionality of the website.

Now I want to update the copy of the repo on my local machine to reflect those changes, but when I do `git pull origin master` it tells me that my version is up to date, though it isn't because those changes aren't there.

How can I incorporate those changes to my local repo?

Comment: Did you do the changes on *master*?

Comment: yes, but they're not merged yet

Comment: what I want to do is get them on my local branch so I can squash them with others

Comment: Weird. What does `git log master..origin/master` show?

Comment: that command shows nothing- is that the exact thing? with those dots? i made the changes by editing directly in the website from the button of the pen, you know what I mean?

Comment: Yes, I also do that sometimes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125918/discussion-between-w0lf-and-s-matthew-english).